# How long does printing to the screen take?

Tags: python

I have a program that goes through everything in a huge list (~14 meg), and performs an operation with each item. I noticed that this took longer when I had it print each item as it iterated over it. So that got me to wondering - how long does it take to print something to the screen? Or more specifically, how much will it slow me down? Is it 'worth it'?

Comment: How long is a rope? That is, it depends on what you're printing, how you're printing it, what terminal software, your graphics card... there are so many factors that there is no single easy answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily measure this kind of things with IPython `%timeit` magic function (see a tutorial [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html)):

```
In [6]: %timeit print('', end='')
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.44 µs per loop
```

Obviously, the actual result will depend on many factors, but you can do some naive benchmarking with this.

Comment: Is it completely dependent on the machine, or does python have some sort of bottleneck?

Comment: Displaying stuff on screen is slow. I'm pretty sure that's true whether you're using Python or any other language.

Comment: Most probably, it will be dependent, to some extent, on the machine, the OS, the application, the version of Python, the load of the system and the will of the ancient gods. If you need precise results, you will have to benchmark as close to reality as possible :/ What do you mean with "does Python have some sort of bottleneck?"? If it is much slower than others? I'm not so sure about it, but I don't think so; it is actually quite normal that doing any IO significantly slows down a CPU-intensive task.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the timeit module.

```
import timeit
```

Check the difference between these two calls.  In these examples number is the number of times the code in stmt is called.

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='print(str1[:5])',setup='str1 = "Hello, World!"',number=1000)
```

vs.

```
timeit.timeit(stmt='str1[:5]',setup='str1 = "Hello, World!"',number=1000)
```